# How to get Nestjs configService instance in main.ts before instantiating app

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config

My app instance depends on configuration : `serviceName` in that case

```
const serviceName = 'authentication-service'
const servicePrefix = `api/${serviceName}`;
const swaggerPrefix = 'swagger';
...
const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new FastifyAdapter({
      requestIdLogLabel: serviceName,
      logger: true,
      ...
    }),
    {
      // logger: ['log']
      logger: process.env.DEV === '1' ? ['log', 'debug', 'error', 'verbose', 'warn'] : ['error', 'warn'],
    });
```

[NestJs documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#using-in-the-maints) uses app instance to get the `configService` singleton :

```
const configService = app.get(ConfigService);
const port = configService.get('PORT');
```

Is there any way to get the `configService` instance before instantiating my app?

Answer (score 4):

Nope. You could call `dotenv`'s `config()` method yourself and populate `process.env` if you really need to, but that's about it. Technically, if you really wannted you could create a `NestFactory.createApplicationContext()` call and get the `ConfigService` from there, close the context and start up the application with the standard `NestFactory.create`, but that will end up doing the DI resolution twice, which would be a pretty slow startup

Comment: Thank's for your quick reply! It seems that NestJs has lost something here. A good framework simplifies things and tries to cover most use cases. One of these standard use case is to get configuration and use it to bootstrap the application (this is what Spring framework does). They do it in reverse here!

Comment: I agree, I need to create an MQTT microservice using the ConfigService to get the url. I can't seem to set the URL after creating the microservice, but i can't get the config before creating the microservice

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar need (for the Mikro-ORM configuration file). What I did is to create a new instance of `ConfigService`:

```js
import {ConfigService} from '@nestjs/config'
const configService = new ConfigService()
```

Then I could use `configService` to get the port number:

```js
configService.get<number>('PSQL_PORT', 5432)
```

---

**Update**

@TheoCerutti commented yesterday that this does not work. It actually does work; I have tested this with Nest 10 on Linux.

Here is a reproduction (tested using BASH).

```bash
# Define the location where the test repository should be located
root_folder="$HOME"

# Generate a new Nest app
(cd "$root_folder" && nest new -p pnpm --strict nest-config-service-in-main)

# Change to the repository folder
cd "$root_folder/nest-config-service-in-main"

# Update the `main.ts` file contents
# Note: I have removed all the unrelated commands from that file,
#       as bootstrapping the Nest app is actually not necessary to make this work.
cat << EOF > "$root_folder/nest-config-service-in-main/src/main.ts"
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

const configService = new ConfigService();
console.log(configService.get<number>('PSQL_PORT', 5432));

async function bootstrap() {
  // Note: You will need to run \`NestFactory.create()\` method, otherwise \`.env\` files won't be loaded.
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  // Note: In real app, you will uncomment this, however for this test, it is not required.
  // await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
EOF

# Update the `src/app.module.ts` file contents
cat << EOF > "$root_folder/nest-config-service-in-main/src/app.module.ts"
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
EOF

# Testing
pnpm i @nestjs/config
pnpm start  # Output: `5432`
PSQL_PORT=2345 pnpm start  # Output: `2345`

# Testing with an `.env` file
cat << EOF > "$root_folder/nest-config-service-in-main/.env"
PSQL_PORT=3333
EOF

pnpm start  # Output: `3333`
```

Comment: i'm surprised but this seems to work, i guess the appModule code is run before this due to importing appmodule, and in appModule you have ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: '.development.env',
    }), 
which is done before you create the configService in bootstrap

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: @TheoCerutti, it does actually work. I have just tested this with Nest 10. See the updated answer.

Comment: Ok yeah it's seems working. I also tried it

Comment: @TheoCerutti, it works for `.env` files too, try now. The previous example was too minimal for your use case. :)

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to create a dummy app instance before the actual app.

```
  const configApp = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  let configService = configApp.get(ConfigService);

  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new FastifyAdapter({
      requestIdLogLabel: serviceName,
      logger: true,
      ...
    }),
    {
      // logger: ['log']
      logger: process.env.DEV === '1' ? ['log', 'debug', 'error', 'verbose', 'warn'] : ['error', 'warn'],
    });
    //...
```

Comment: this actually is a good answer

Comment: This works BUT it actually starts a full app including possible database and microservice connections, etc - Not a good solution IMO

Answer (score 0):

I am using custom configuration files as defined in https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#custom-configuration-files

and with that I can use just use the following to get access to the config already in a js object.

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const conf = configuration();
  ...
```

I initiall tried the solution from tukusejssirs which also worked but it would not map the env entries to js object yet so I came up with this one.

Comments appreciated as it feels a bit weird...